# Algorithm - Finding the most rewarding path in a given graph

Tags: algorithm, python-2.7, dynamic-programming

**Question**: You are given the following inputs:

```
3
0 0 1
3 1 1
6 0 9
```

The first line is the number of points on the graph.
The rest of the lines contain the points on the graph, and their reward. For example:

0 0 1 would mean at point (0,0) [which is the starting point] you are given a reward of 1.

3 1 1 would mean at point (3,1) you are given a reward of 1.

6 0 9 would mean at point (6, 0) you are given a reward of 9.

Going from point a, to point b costs 1.

Therefore if you go from (0,0) -> (3,1) -> (6,0) your reward is 11-2 (cost of traversing 2 nodes) * sqrt(10).

**Goal**: Determine the maximum amount of rewards you can make (the total amount of reward you collect - the cost) based on the provided inputs.

How would I go about solving this? It seems like dynamic programming is the way to go, but I am not sure where to start.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem it isn't necessarily the longest path that would maximize the reward. You can skip points if you want to, the only constraint is that you start at (0,0) and end at point n (the last point).

Comment: @Jorge: "*or (in weighted graphs) by the sum of the weights of its edges*" (wikipage).